# How to download Images from netsuite and place it in an excel workbook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, netsuite, spreadsheet

I'm trying to implement this code that I prepared from various snippets from StackOverflow itself that enables the macro to add an extra column and place the images contained in links in **column B**. Since links from **NetSuite** does not contain the file type of the image, I had to download the image to a local folder, rename the image using the names in **column A** with **.jpg** extension and then re-insert the images into the newly created column C in order for excel to actually detect these images. The problem now is that the code that I wrote is not compatible with 64-bit systems, and reacts differently with different excel version/filetypes. Like if I save the workbook in .xls format, the code completely breaks. Since I'm relatively very new to VBA, please find me a solution to make this 64 bit compatible and iron out the random behavior with different versions/filetypes. Suggestions to improve the logic is also welcome. Attaching the spreadsheet sample with this comment: [Spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15cJLRW3bhw5NzoHkDXyPk-v93DDrdxd-/view?usp=sharing)

```
    Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Dim Ret As Long


Function createFolder() As String

         If Len(Dir("E:\Workspace\Temp", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then       '<~~ specify the directory for image dump
            MkDir "E:\Workspace\Temp"
         End If
         createFolder = "E:\Workspace\Temp\"
End Function

    
Sub DownloadPics()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim FolderName As String
    
    FolderName = createFolder()
    '~~> Name of the sheet which has the list
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow    '<~~ loop to download and rename to JPEG
        strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"                          '<~~ column A used for reference/ID for the images

        Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

        If Ret = 0 Then                                                        '<~~ Used to check the download status,change the column/ delete IF statement, upto the user
            ws.Range("E" & i).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
        Else
            ws.Range("E" & i).Value = "Unable to download the file"
        End If
    Next i

    Dim fPath As String, fName As String
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range
    Dim shpPic As Shape

    Columns("C:C").Select                '<~~ that extra column for the images
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    fPath = FolderName
    Set rng = Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)     '<~~ column A used for reference/ID for the images
    For Each r In rng
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    If r.Value <> "" Then                               '<~~ loop to insert image back into the sheet
        Set shpPic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=fPath & r.Value & ".jpg", linktofile:=msoFalse, _
            savewithdocument:=msoTrue, Left:=Cells(r.Row, 3).Left, Top:=Cells(r.Row, 3).Top, Width:=-1, Height:=-1)
        With shpPic
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            If .Width > Columns(2).Width Then .Width = Columns(2).Width
            Rows(r.Row).RowHeight = .Height
        End With
    End If

errHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
       Debug.Print Err.Number & ", " & Err.Description & ", " & r.Value
       On Error GoTo -1
    End If
    Next r
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
        Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
            ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
            ByVal szURL As String, _
            ByVal szFileName As String, _
            ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, _
            ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr _
        ) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
        Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
            ByVal pCaller As Long, _
            ByVal szURL As String, _
            ByVal szFileName As String, _
            ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
            ByVal lpfnCB As Long _
        ) As Long
#End If
```

I also recommend putting your Application.ScreenUpdateing = False at the beginning of your sub.

Also, Exit Sub before your error handler

Comment: This solved the 64-bit error, but the code needed further revisions so had to re-do some parts. Thank you for your help.